# Removing an implemented interface using AST

Tags: eclipse-jdt

I'm trying to modify source code in a standalone project using the eclipse jdt core, one of the problems I faced is removing an interface implementation.

```
public class RandomClass implements Interface1, Interface2 {
...
}
```

I want to remove `Interface2`, does anyone know how can we implement the ASTRewrite to perform such task?